# Redis Sentinel 3.2 not firing scripts

Tags: redis, ubuntu-16.04, redis-sentinel

So we just `apt` updated Redis to v3.2.8 (from 3.0.7) on our Ubuntu 16.04 servers, and have noticed that the `client-reconfig-script` and `notification-script` doesn't seem to fire anymore, on failover events.

We tested with `debug sleep 30` and we can manipulate the sentinels to failover just fine, but the scripts do not fire.

Relevant info:

- We're using the config files from 3.2 (we had to, as our own were replaced by the updater).
- In `sentinel.conf`, the paths to the two scripts are correct:

`sentinel notification-script ourmaster /mnt/efs/scripts/sentinel-notify.sh`
`sentinel client-reconfig-script ourmaster /mnt/efs/scripts/sentinel-failover.sh`

- We've even changed the permissions on these files to `redis:redis`, but still nothing.
- We've turned protected mode off, on both redis and sentinel.
- `bind` is commented out, as we need to bind to all adapters, but we've also tried `bind 0.0.0.0`
- Everything else seem to work, its just these two scripts.
- Running the scripts manually still works.

Anyone have any ideas?

Is it even supported anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using this unofficial Ubuntu PPA for Redis upgrades:
https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/redis-server

The official PPA still uses 3.0.7, so we rolled back to that, and the problem went away.

The only theory I have is that Redis was built incorrectly in Chris' PPA. We've tried everything else at this point.